# GDPR Consent Dialog won't show

Tags: java, android, admob, cookieconsent

i'm trying to add the **GDPR Consent** `dialog` to my application by using th new Consent SDK by Google ,(I do not live in the EU) but i can't here's my code when i run it the dialog won't open, i tried to use VPN but still the same dialog doesn't appears

```
/*GDRP*/
        ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this);
        String[] publisherIds = {"pub-xxxxx...."};
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {

            }
        });
        URL privacyUrl = null;
        try {
            // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
            privacyUrl = new URL("URL");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle error.
        }
        form = new ConsentForm.Builder(this, privacyUrl)
                .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoaded(){
                        showForm();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormClosed(
                            ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    }
                })
                .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withAdFreeOption()
                .build();

        form.load();

 private void showForm() {
        form.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue. The problem is that the form is not fully loaded when you trying to show it, due to a bug in the SDK.

This should solve it:

```
 // declare your form up
 ConsentForm form;

 // declare this function that will show the form
 protected void showConsentForm(){
     form.show();
 }


 // on the onCreate 
 form = new ConsentForm.Builder(context, privacyUrl)
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Consent form loaded successfully.
                    Log.d("SplashScreen", "Consent form Loaded ");
                    showConsentForm();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    // Consent form was displayed.
                    Log.d("SplashScreen", "Consent form opened ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                        ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form was closed.
                    Log.d("SplashScreen", "Consent form Closed ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.
                    Log.d("SplashScreen", "Consent form error " + errorDescription);
                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .build();
// load the form so we can call .show on it after
form.load();
```

Comment: Holy s4it! you were right. there seems to be a bug. I implemented it with a delay though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this line to test in non-EU region.

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).
    setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Alexandru Topală](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984011/alexandru-topal%c4%83) mentioned, you can't call `show()` right after `load()`.

Very poorly documented...

I implemented it with kotlin, and `late init`:

```kotlin
lateinit var form: ConsentForm
form = ConsentForm.Builder(this@HomeActivity, privacyUrl)
        .withListener(object : ConsentFormListener() {
            override fun onConsentFormLoaded() {
                form.show()
            }

            override fun onConsentFormOpened() {}

            override fun onConsentFormClosed(consentStatus: ConsentStatus, userPrefersAdFree: Boolean) {
                viewModel.consentUpdate(consentStatus)
                if (userPrefersAdFree) {
                    PurchaseActivity.startActivity(this@HomeActivity)
                }
            }

            override fun onConsentFormError(errorDescription: String) {
                Timber.e(RuntimeException(errorDescription), "Failed to open consent form.")
            }
        })
        .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
        .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
        .withAdFreeOption()
        .build()
form.load()
```